# Do adjoining basepoints and/or moduli of spaces affect fixed points nicely?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology, gt.geometric-topology

My question is when will $(X_+)^G$ or $(X/A)^G$ be equal to $(X^G)_+$ or $X^G/A^G$ respectively for $X$ a $G$-space, $G$ a finite cyclic group and $X^G$ the ordinary fixed points. These seem like they would be very nice features but I don't have a concrete reason why they would ever be true.

There's a specific scenario I'd like to solve this for. I'm working on proving that a specific $C_2$-spectrum is real oriented as defined in [Hill–Hopkins–Ravenel - On the non-existence of elements of Kervaire invariant one](https://arxiv.org/abs/0908.3724). I have a way of computing the equivariant cohomology of a space with coefficients in this spectrum but it involves $C_2$-fixed points of $\mathbb{C}P^\infty_+$ and $\mathbb{C}P^\infty/\mathbb{C}P^1$. Note: Hill–Hopkins–Ravenel equip $\mathbb{C}P^n$ with the $C_2$ action by complex conjugation such that $(\mathbb{C}P^n)^{C_2} = \mathbb{R}P^n$ for all $n$.

It would be very convenient for my calculations if $(\mathbb{C}P^\infty/\mathbb{C}P^1)^{C_2} = \mathbb{R}P^\infty/\mathbb{R}P^1$ and $(\mathbb{C}P^\infty_+)^{C_2} = \mathbb{R}P^\infty_+$ were true. I'm more convinced on the adjoined basepoint since we could adjoin the basepoint at the origin so that complex conjugation would have no effect. The modulo problem seems a lot more complicated, I worry that I am not thinking of everything that could go wrong.

I'd appreciate any sort of input about solving fixed point problems.

Comment: It seemed like you were using 'adjoint' where you might mean 'adjoined' (as in, "a base point has been adjoined"), and I edited accordingly.  If I misunderstood a technical term, then please feel free to revert or correct my edit.

Comment: Fixed points in genuine $C_2$-spaces commute with all homotopy limits and colimits (essentially by the definition of the model structure). So the answer to your questions is yes in all cases, but basically by definition...

Comment: Awesome, thank you both!